# CSS columns hide ::before element with absolute position extending his own column

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-multicolumn-layout

on my site, I have triangles maded from borders of pseudo element :before. My problem is, if i add these triangles to elements in columns (`column-count`), triangles in not first column are hidden under previous column. Columns have `column-gap` set. I tried `z-index:` and it won't work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/208715/

```css
    .masonry{
      column-count: 3;
      column-gap: 1.5em;
    }
    
    .child {
      height: 400px;
      background: #EEE;
    }
    
    span{
      left: -20px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    span:before{
      content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 0 1.5em .5em;
        border-color: transparent transparent #D36135 transparent;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="masonry p-1">
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take the code from your fiddle and convert it into a snippet here.

Comment: `.masonry{
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.child {
  height: 400px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin-left:1.5em;
}`

Comment: @Jasonbamber that will work, but there will be margin-left on first column too. Sure i can remove it with Javascript (get coordinates of child, detect if is in first column a than remove), but it's not a fancy solution

Comment: `.container{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.masonry{
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
  margin-left:-0.75rem;
}

.child {
  height: 400px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin-left:1.5rem;
}`

Comment: @Jasonbamber make answer, i will mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add to `.child` this css:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/208715/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="masonry p-1">
    <div class="child">
      <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.masonry{
   column-count: 3;
   column-gap: 1.5em;
 }

.child {
   height: 400px;
   background: #EEE;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
   break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}

span{
   left: -20px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
}

span:before{
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0 0 1.5em .5em;
   border-color: transparent transparent #D36135 transparent;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `h1{position:relative;}` and `.child {margin-left:20px;}`

```css
.masonry{
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
}

.child {
  height: 400px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin-left:20px;
}

span{
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.position-relative{
position:relative;
}

span:before{
  content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1.5em .5em;
    border-color: transparent transparent #D36135 transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="masonry p-1">
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1<span></span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you want, but if you want all triangles before the column then I have made some tweaks. I have moved all the span from h1 to parent div (.child) and added position:relative; to .child class.

You can also check it here.. http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/208868/

```css
.masonry{
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
}
.child {
  height: 400px;
  background: #EEE;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin-left:20px;
}

span{
  margin-left: -32px;
}
span:before{
  content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 3em 2em;
    border-color: transparent transparent #D36135 transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="masonry p-1">
  <div class="child"><span></span>
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child"><span></span>
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child"><span></span>
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child"><span></span>
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child"><span></span>
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child"><span></span>
  <h1 class="position-relative">h1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is still same problem here
http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/208838/

i need triangle to be outside of his column and all visible

Comment: So if you add   margin-left:20px; to .child class style then it will work.  http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/208868/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a margin instead of `column-gap`, and set a negative margin on the container to align the left hand side:

```
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.masonry{
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
  margin-left:-0.75rem;
}

.child {
  height: 400px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin-left:1.5rem;
}
```